# How to use Google Guava's Preconditions.checkElementIndex?

Tags: java, guava

The api doc said:  Ensures that index specifies a valid element in an array, list or string of size size.

But where pass the 'target' array or list string in this method?

Comment: This is a good question - it exposes how inconsistent Java APIs are. I would even expect common interface for classes having size/length.

Answer (score 6):

The element inside the `Array` , `List` and `String` can be accessed using the 0-based index.

Suppose you want to access  a particular  element from a List using an index .Before calling `list.get(index)` ,  you may use the following to check this `index`  is between 0 and `list.size()` to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException` :

```
 if (index < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("index must be positive");
 } else if (index >= list.size()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("index must be less than size of the list");
 }
```

The purpose of `Preconditions` class is to replace  this  checking with the more compact one

```
Preconditions.checkElementIndex(index,list.size());
```

So , you don't need to pass the whole target list instance .Instead , you just need to  pass the size of the target list to this method.

Answer (score 3):

The method Precondition.checkElementIndex(...) does not care about the 'target'. You simply pass the `size` and the `index`, as follows:

```
public String getElement(List<String> list, int index) {
  Preconditions.checkElementIndex(index, list.size(), "The given index is not valid");
  return list.get(index);
}
```

According to [Guava's reference](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkElementIndex%28int,%20int%29), the method `checkElementIndex` could be implemented as follows:

```
public class Preconditions {
  public static int checkElementIndex(int index, int size) {
    if (size < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return index;
  }
}
```

As you can see, there's no need for it to know the List, Array, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "target" to know whether an int index is valid for a given size of list, string, or array. If `index >= 0 && index < [list.size()|string.length()|array.length]` then it's valid, else not.